# User.drafts reference - error"Invalid to header"

Tags: gmail-api

One of our components imports email drafts using the Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create). This component was deployed more than one month ago and was working fine until last Friday.

Since Friday the draft creation requests have been failing when the email contains more than one recipient. The error message is "Invalid to header" (400).

Is this a temp. issue or can you please help to fix this?

Comment: Having the same issue.  I'm finding that it happens when I have more than one recipient in a given field fwiw.  Maybe an issue where Gmail doesn't like how the recipients are delimited?

Answer (score 0):

It was a regression that we fixed on 2014-08-25.

Comment: It's Monday, any news?

Comment: Yep, the fix finished rolling out Monday early afternoon (US/Pacific) as you probably noticed...